# How to encode password?

Tags: php, symfony

I'am very new to symfony2, so this might be a little lame question ;-)
I have form which edits 2 etities - Worker and User. Both are related. User is for loging and worker store additional information about user (in system I have 3 different kind of user: worker, client and admin). Below is generated updateAction and all i want is to encode password before save edited user. How to do that?

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Worker')->find($id);

if (!$entity) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Worker entity.');
}

$deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
$editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
$editForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($editForm->isValid()) {

    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('worker_edit', array('id' => $id)));
}

return $this->render('MainBundle:Worker:edit.html.twig', array(
    'entity'      => $entity,
    'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
    'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation regarding encoding passwords [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password)

Basically you will call for the security factory get the user you going to encode for, get the encoder and then encode the password.

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$user = //get the user from the worker entity or just use the worker entity


$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$theSuppliedPassword = // however they are supplying the password, likely $entity->getPassword();
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($theSuppliedPassword, $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```